# How to set a different space for the first bullet point?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I have a Paragraph style called Bullet List. Like all my basic paragraphs, I need the list to have a space-before of one line (14.3pt). However I would also like to be able to control the space between the bullets independently of this. It seems that the only way I can change the spacing between the bullets is to change the space-before value, but this also effects the space-before the first bullet.

How can I set one value for the space-before the first bullet, and a different value for the space-before the subsequent bullets?

Comment: Do you mean a line space (leading) of 14.3? As in is the space you're trying to adjust horizontal between each bullet? Or vertical between the bullet and the margin and/or bullet and its adjacent text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'll need to create two paragraph styles.

1)  Create a paragraph style (bullet style #1) for the first line of the bullet list.

2)  Duplicate that first paragraph style and rename it (ex. bullet style #2) and add a "left indent" value.

3)  Go back to the first paragraph style (bullet style #1) and make sure you select paragraph style (bullet style #2) as the "Next Style".

4)  Now select the unformatted bullet list and apply paragraph style (bullet style #1).

This should give you the desired result. Hope this helps.